# Custom body message in riemann email

Tags: clojure, riemann

I am trying to create a custom message in the body section of email using riemann.
I couldn't append the field dynamically.

**Riemann config:**

```
(let [email (mailer 
              {:host "XXXXX" :port XX :user "XXX" :pass "XXX" :auth "true"
               :subject (fn [events] "Team")
               :body (fn [events] 
                       (apply str "Hello Team, now the time is" (:timestamp event) "Thank You!"))
               :from "xxx@gmail.com"})]
```

**My output:**

```
Hello Team, now the time is Thank You!
```

**My expected output:**

```
Hello Team, now the time is 12:13:45 Thank You!.
```

My timestamp not getting appended in the :body.

Comment: your param there is `events` and you read from `event` (missing s). start with  `(pr-str events)` first, to see what you get.

Comment: I tried with `(pr-str events)` I am getting the event `:timestamp.` But when i tried it with `(apply str "Hello Team, now the time is" (:timestamp events) "Thank You!")).` I am not getting the value of `:timestamp` getting appended with my string.

Comment: please add the pr-str to the question

Answer (score 0):

from [the docs](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.email.html):

```
These formatting functions take a sequence of
events and return a string.
```

so the question is which event in the sequence would you like to get the timestamp from? If you lookup a keyword in a sequence, as opposed to one of the members of that sequence, you will get back `nil` as a default:

```
core> (:asdf '(1 2 3))
nil
```

and if you `apply str` that into a couple other strings it will have no effect because `str` will ignore it. Which is where your output is coming from. Here is an analogous example function:

```
core> (let [body-fn (fn [events]
                        (apply str "Hello Team, now the time is"
                               (:timestamp events)
                               "Thank You!"))]
        (body-fn [{:timestamp 42} {:timestamp 43}]))
"Hello Team, now the time isThank You!"
```

if we choose the timestamp from the first event:

```
core> (let [body-fn (fn [events]
                        (apply str "Hello Team, now the time is"
                               (:timestamp (first events))
                               "Thank You!"))]
        (body-fn [{:timestamp 42} {:timestamp 43}]))
"Hello Team, now the time is42Thank You!"
```

When alerting through riemann my personal opinion is to wrap the things being alerted into fixed time windows and use the timestamp from the start of that window, though this is primarily because of personal preference.

Comment: I have updated my code with this method `(:timestamp (first events))` but still i am not getting the value which I am passing to riemann.

Comment: are you still getting emails send with the string "Hello Team, now the time is Thank You!" ? (which would indicate that it's still nil) or are you not getting the emails at all?

Comment: I am getting the email but I am still getting this string only "Hello Team, now the time is Thank You!", my custom field `:timestamp` value didn't get append with my message